# is possible export value of this.state.islogin

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

at this moment that in the whole legin code in a single page file,
but I wanted to be able to check in any one if the user was logged in exporting the value of islogin if it is true or missing but without repeating the code everywhere
thank you already who can help

i have my file with config firestore:

```
const config = {
apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
databaseURL: "",
projectId: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "",
appId: "",
measurementId: ""
  };

  const firebaseApp=firebase.initializeApp(config);
  const fb=firebase.firestore();

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { 
    this.state = {
      islogin: false,
    };
    if (user) {
        this.setState({islogin: true});  // value to export
        console.log('logggn')
        console.log(user.displayName);
      } else {
        this.setState({islogin: false}); // value to export
        console.log('nologin');
      }
  });
 

  export const auth = firebase.auth();
  export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
  export const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  export default fb;
```

and I'm trying to export the value of 'islogin' so I can use it anywhere

is possible?

Answer (score 0):

State is saved to component, not to the app. You need to use AsyncStorage or Redux
https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage

**Example #1 (with bad practice - you should separate config from the functions and JSX):**

In your config file:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

const firebaseApp=firebase.initializeApp(config);
const fb=firebase.firestore();

const saveIsLogin = async (isLogin) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('isLogin', isLogin); // First param is name of value, second value of that variable which will be stored in the app (it's something like localStorege in web)
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { 
  const isLogin = user ? true : false; // if user exists set true, if not set false

  saveIsLogin(isLogin);
});

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
export default fb;
```

In your second file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLogin: this.getIsLogin()
    }
  }

  getIsLogin = async () => {
    let isLogin = false;
    try {
      isLogin = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLogin') || false;
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data
      console.log(error.message);
    }

    return isLogin;
  }

  render () {
    return (<Text>{this.state.isLogin}</Text>);
  }
}
```

**Example #2:**

firebase.js:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config)
}

export { firebase };
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { firebase } from './firebase';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { 
      const isLogin = user ? true : false;
    
      this.saveIsLogin(isLogin);
    });
  }

  saveIsLogin = async (isLogin) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('isLogin', isLogin);
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (<SomeComponents>);
  }
}
```

LoggedScreen.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLogin: this.getIsLogin()
    }
  }

  getIsLogin = async () => {
    let isLogin = false;
    try {
      isLogin = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLogin') || false;
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data
      console.log(error.message);
    }

    return isLogin;
  }

  render () {
    return (<Text>{this.state.isLogin}</Text>);
  }
}
```